# Creating a smart remote upload script with jQuery AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently creating an image hosting script and so far so good. I've used several plugins to create the local uploading process with drag & drog + AJAX which works totally fine. Now I've moved to the part where I need to create the remote uploading process with jQuery AJAX and a PHP script to handle the whole thing.

### How it's gonna work

My thought are like this: There is a big box in the middle of the page that accepts the URLs to be remote uploaded. Once **valid** URL(s) are passed into the text area, they will be immediately sent to the server side script via jQuery AJAX. It's bound with a `keyup` event.

**This is how it looks like:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNBFT.png. 
The *"HERE COME THE URLS"* part is already a text area - So that part's already done.

---

### Where I need help

The issue with this whole situation is: Once there are valid URLs pasted into the text area, those must be immediately be converted to some sort of box which also includes an uploading progress. Something that looks like this (copied from the local uploading part): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YleJ.png

It was easy implement the progress indicator for the local uploading, since it was a feature offered by the plugin I've used, but **I don't know how to indicate the progress of remote uploading**, which is totally being made from scratch.

So this is how I've imagined the logic to flow:

1. User pastes some URLs into the text area
2. There is a client-side check to validate the pasted URLs
3. Validated URLs are send to **upload.php** on `keyup` <strike>*(?)*</strike>
4. URLs are being processed
5. While the upload goes on, we show the users the progress in the **[knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/)** *(?)*
6. PHP script finishes the process and returns back the uploaded URLs
7. I update the page in the AJAX `success` callback to display the uploaded files

So, the two process flows marked with *(?)* are unclear to me - I don't know how to achieve those...

---

### What I have tried

Well, I didn't just come here and ask you to do everything for me, but I've come across a dead end and I don't know how to continue. What I've done so far is collect the URLs from the text area, and if there are multiple URLs separated by a line break (`\n`), I simply use `split` to get an array of pasted text and then use another function inside the loop to validate if they are URLs. If there is no line break detected inside the text area value, then I simply check the one line that was provided. On each case, I send the whole text area to the PHP script, because **I don't know how to get rid of the invalid URLs in jQuery**. I've created a function called `debug()` in PHP which stores anything into a *debug.log* file and this is what I'm getting (in one try) when I paste something into the text area:

```
https://www.google.com/https://www.google.com/
```

I paste `https://www.google.com/` once in the text area, but it gets logged twice in the PHP side and I can't determine why.

**This is how my jQuery looks like:**

```
// Remote upload
    var char_start  = 10;
    var index       = 0;
    var urls        = $('.remote-area');
    var val_ary     = [];

    urls.keyup(function(){      
        if (urls.val().length >= char_start)
        {           
            var has_lbrs = /\r|\n/i.test(urls.val());
            val_ary = urls.val().split('\n');

            if (has_lbrs)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < val_ary.length; i++)
                {
                    if (!validate_url(val_ary[i]))
                    {
                        val_ary.splice(i, 1);
                        continue;   
                    }       
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    data: {
                        upload_type: 'remote', // Used to determine the upload type in PHP
                        urls: val_ary, // Sending the whole array here
                    },
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if (!validate_url(urls.val()))
                {
                    // Display an error here
                    return; 
                }

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'upload.php',
                    data: {
                        upload_type: 'remote', // Used to determine the upload type in PHP
                        urls: urls.val(), // Sending what's in the text area
                    },
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

---

### The questions

So the final questions are:

- <strike>How do I send my information correctly to the PHP script, only valid URLs and have them kind of "process-able" in my PHP script</strike>.
- How do I indicate the progress of the upload?

*If I was somewhere unclear during my question, please let me know, I'll try to reexplain.*

Thank you.

---

### Updates

**09/12/2013**

I think I have managed to solve the double-sending issue where my AJAX would send the same information twice to the PHP script. What I did was code in a delay anonymous function that sends the text area content to the PHP script **after** an user stops typing for 2 seconds. Once the user stops typing again, the timer resets and a new AJAX request will be made. So, I'm assuming that this issue has been solved. I'll come back to it if anything strange occurs.

Now I'm still left with the progress indicators part. I'd appreciate your thoughts on that one.

**My new code:** http://pastebin.com/SaFSLeE9

Comment: The only person to ever format their Stack Overflow question correctly.  Got me all teary-eyed over here

Comment: Is it possible the url gets logged twice because it's sent twice? Binding to the `keyup` risks sending the url while it's being typed. To check validity of url you could do a HEAD request via jQuery to check if it is valid (HEAD only returns the headers, not the file). And it may be a good idea to cache all urls you've already checked/sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for in terms of communicating progress back and forth is "pushing". That refers to the technique of server sending data to the client, rather than the other way around, which is the standard HTTP way of doing things.

You've got plenty of options available, as described in the explanatory [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), though perhaps more relevant to this topic would be [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). What happens is you trigger and `$.ajax` call just like the one you have now, but you set a very long timeout. That essentially gives the server a "channel" to send data back to the page whenever it's available.

So what you need is a `.php` on the server that is capable of handling long polling and will send data back to the page as the upload progress changes (probably in array form for multiple uploads). [This article](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) should get you started with some jQuery code. Just remember that this request *doesn't* go to `upload.php`. This request goes to a different script that deals solely with upload percentages and only returns data when that is available, it doesn't return immediately as all others scripts - the Ajax will happily wait for the data.

Also, don't separate your code like that with `has_lbrs`. One line or many are not distinct cases, one line is just an edge case of many lines. You're duplicating the code unnecessarily. What does the `else` case do that would break in the general case? Further, the "error handling" in the `else` case is misleading. The only error reporting you do is if there is only one line and it's wrong. What if you have two lines and they're both wrong? Your code will happily send an empty array to `upload.php`.

This is why I think you shouldn't separate your code like that, because then you'll split logic and not even notice it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd like to ask some questions... Let's say I've created that polling system in my jQuery, but what do I send to my PHP script that deals with the percentages? What do I send back from the script to the AJAX call? Those are the questions that are puzzling me. I'd also like to mention that my Javascript has changed a bit from the question; I'll be updating it once I get the chance.

Comment: You send back the percentages you want to update the progress bars with, every time you want to update it. You don't need to send anything to it, the ajax is just a request for data. If you're asking "how do I get the script to calculate percentages", well, that depends on your backend upload script, which you haven't provided. You just need some way of the upload script to update <some counter> with its progress and then have the update script read the <some counter> and send it back to the polling ajax request.

Comment: So if I provided a server side script, would you be able to give me a visual on some example code? Just a brief example, something to get me started. I'll try to give a short description on what the PHP script does: It grabs the URL with `file_get_content`, checks the file's extension with a function which I'll provide and then stores the file in the server with `file_put_contents`. It's actually a pretty simple script.

Comment: That will nicely crash your server on large files. If you want to do this right, you'll have to use binary streams from the source into the destination file, without reading the entire thing into the memory first. Try something like http://teddy.fr/2007/11/28/how-serve-big-files-through-php/ - that should make it trivial for you to update <some counter> in between writing the file chunks. Then the other script can simply read the <some counter> that you're updating and report progress back to the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinoin, the best way is to call your cURL script with ajax and use it to upload your files on remote server. You need ajax.js, curl.php, index.php (whatever name you want) on your app server. And image.php, class.image.php (whatever name you want) on your remote server.

Steps that I did for my app

1) I am going to upload an image from my index.php file. It will call curl.php file using ajax.js and the cURL file will check file's extension and all (for your app's security, make sure what you want to allow users to upload).

2) Now the curl file will upload the file to your pre defined temporary folder with the default file name.

3) Now if move_uploaded_file function (which I used in my script) run successfully, you can call your cURL function to send your data as post on your remote server, where image file will receive posts and will process further. You can keep your class in image.php or you can create two PHP files on your remote server, as you want.

4) Now in your class file, you should check file once again that it is image file (and whatever you want to allow) or not for better security. If file is good, process to rename it and add file into folder if you want to.

5) Add file's new name and folder name into your database by using remote database connection. So, cURL will show you result on the same page.

Now, why cURL? I prefer cURL because, you can add secret key or API for your communication to make it more secure, with if else conditions. Your remote server file which is going to receive all posts, will check if API == 'yourKey' then will process other wise it wont process and nobody will be able to send images on your server with bots and all.

I don't know that my answer is going to help you or not, probably my method is lengthy or not good for your app, but try to Google about cURL and you will understand what I am trying to say. Hope you like it and understood it. If any doubt, you can ask me any time.

Comment: I'm very familiar with cURL, it's Javascript I suck at, haha. Actually I use cURL to validate the uploaded files' extensions already and that's the safe way to go. I definitely will consider this kind of implementation. Thank you for the suggestion.